# Transferring money won in Las Vegas to Europe

Tags: united-states, international-transfer, customs

A European gambler makes a trip to Las Vegas in the USA. He manages to win a good amount of money, say 50,000 USD.

Now it would be unwise to walk around with this amount of cash in his pocket; he can get robbed. It would be even more unwise to take the profits as cash on his flight home to Europe. There are strict rules on how much money you can import. If you are over the limit, the money can be confiscated by Customs on the airport. You would then have to prove that you had a legitimate reason for having so much money on you. Just saying: "I won in Las Vegas" won't work.

Ideally you would like to have your winnings transferred to your (European) bank account. But how would this work? Do banks in Las Vegas provide this service? Or the casinos (they have the appearance of being consumer friendly) ? Or is there a Western Union (or similar company) who is willing to transfer the money?

Answer (score 5):

> There are strict rules on how much money you can import.

No. There are strict rules on how much money you can bring in without declaring it to customs.

> You would then have to prove that you had a legitimate reason for having so much money on you. Just saying: "I won in Las Vegas" won't work.

Why not? Unless it is illegal in your country to gamble anywhere in the world, this is as legitimate as it gets. It it is illegal to earn money by gambling - then *how* you transfer the money shouldn't matter.

> Ideally you would like to have your winnings transferred to your (European) bank account. But how would this work?

Same way you deposit any other money into your bank account.

> Do banks in Las Vegas provide this service?

Yes. You can convert the cash into traveler's checks, deposit it into a bank account that you open, or request a cashier's check. Note that it is going to require some documentation and reporting for money laundry and tax evasion detection purposes.

> Or the casinos (they have the appearance of being consumer friendly) ?

Maybe. For starters, you can most likely get the casino give you a check for such an amount and not cash. It is very probable that for such an amount they'd agree to wire it to your bank account.

> Or is there a Western Union (or similar company) who is willing to transfer the money?

[Western Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Union) is an American company, so yes - there are in fact multiple [Western Union offices in Las Vegas](https://www.google.com/search?q=Western%20Union%20offices%20in%20Las%20Vegas).

Comment: In addition to declaring on arrival, taking over USD10k 'currency or monetary instruments' _out_ of US must be declared -- and if you don't use the website since US doesn't normally have any outbound immigration check you must proactively find someone to take the form, maybe in an unfamiliar airport with little time before your flight; see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/102872/how-to-submit-required-forms-to-customs-when-leaving-usa .

Answer (score 4):

I do a fair bit of business in Europe and I transfer the money back and forth using https://wise.com/ (no advertisement or endorsement intended). Above a certain limit they do ask where the money is from but that limit is significantly above 50k. "Proceeds from gambling" would be a perfectly good answer specifically if you can provide the receipt from the casino.  Casinos have to report larger winnings to the tax authorities anyway. The whole tax implication is complicated but beside the point of the question (I think).

It is NOT a good idea to run around in the US with lots of cash in your pocket. It's certainly not illegal but there is a bizarre mechanism called "civil forfeiture" that allows police to just steal it from you, even if you haven't done anything wrong at all. It's essentially legalized highway robbery to subsidize local and federal police departments.

Most reputable (whatever that means) casinos will offer you different options to collect and transfer the winnings often will include ACH , bank or wire transfers. However, they may charge you a hefty fee for it, so care is advised.